# how to get the table data in place of table object_new Object in Django

Tags: python, django

i want the data so that i can perform operations on them but i get this Order_table Object(1) and so .

[Screenshot of table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4C0Cr.png)

[models.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/szJch.png)

Thanks

[Table tag use in the template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PKY0H.png)

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. You may want to read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit your question...

Comment: i have gone through other links but failed to understand how to solve this problem.. plz help me .   thanks

Comment: I'm afraid your "problem" is quite unclear - actually I just don't have a clue what you're asking for. And please don't tell that you cannot find how to read records from your database using the ORM, because this is extensively documented in both the tutorial and manual.

Comment: i m new to Django ORM , currently developing an application for my college project. i have 3 tables in my models.py file . the 3rd table is having 2 foreign key from the 1st and 2nd table. by applying table_name.objects.all() command the 1st and 2nd table is showing records , but for the 3rd table its not working . you can see the screenshot above . i want the data in place of (order_table object 1 , item_table object1 ) . i have attached the code of my models.py file as well.

Comment: Please attach your `template` code.

Comment: And avoid attaching screenshots of code. Please post actual code.

Comment: i think these is a problem in my ORM query or models.py file thats why i m unable to get the records as numeric .

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access `id` attribute of your foreign key relation with

```
{{ item.order_id }}
```

`order_id` is your actual field name. This field does not return the id of related object rather returns related object itself. If you want to show id of related object, you have to do

```
{{ item.order_id.id }}
```

and

```
{{ item.item_id.id }}
```

Comment: would be better to fix the model instead, renaming "order_id" to "order". Also, no need to do an extra query just to get the id of the related model, it's directly accessible as "relatedfieldname_id", ie in the above case it would be `item.order_id_id` and `item.item_id_id`